# Post from Razor page clears Model values - when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, html-select

I have a simple single page ASP.NET Core Razor app that has a "select" in it that I am populating from a Model variable. The values in the Model variable are cleared by the time that I examine them in the OnPost() method. (The variable named machineModel returns just fine but the variable named machineModels in the Model is cleared by the Post.) What is doing this?

Here's what the Index.cshtml looks like:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div class="text-left">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   Model: <select name="machineModel" asp-for="machineModel" asp-items="Model.machineModels" required></select>
   <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Download" value="Download certificate" />
</form>
</div>
```

Here's what the Index.cshtml.cs looks like:

```
[BindProperties]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   public string machineModel { get; set; }
   public List<SelectListItem> machineModels = new List<SelectListItem>();

   // In some other function in the class the machineModels variable is filled (several times) ...

   string modelStr = reader.GetAttribute("value");
   int numMachineModels = machineModels.Count;
   string machineModelIndexStr = numMachineModels.ToString();   
   machineModels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = modelStr, Value = machineModelIndexStr, Selected = true });

   // And here's the Post method ...

   public IActionResult OnPostDownload()
   {
      // Doesn't matter what's in here, machineModels is already cleared at this point

      return Page();
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,
Rich

Comment: Try to declare machineModeles like a property.

Answer (score 0):

You do not post the value of  `machineModels` from view to hanlder, try to add below code in your form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div>
        @{ int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var x in Model.machineModels)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="machineModels[@i].Text" value="@x.Text" />
            <input type="hidden" name="machineModels[@i].Value" value="@x.Value" />
            i++;
        }
    </div>
     Model: <select name="machineModel" asp-for="machineModel" asp- 
       items="Model.machineModels" required></select>
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Download" value="Download 
  certificate" />
</form>
```

PageModel:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<SelectListItem> machineModels { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

Comment: Thanks Xing but I don't understand the intent. In my code I use machineModels in a "select" statement. How would the code you propose fill the "select" statement? I assume your code would be in addition to mine. Looks like your code would populate hidden fields - so that they would get posted? machineModels don't need to be posted - because  machineModel will tell me what they selected - they just have to be left alone. Why is machineModels getting cleared? Thanks

Comment: I tried adding your code. I left my "select" statement as it was. machineModels still got cleared - but I did have access to the Texts and Values that were in the hidden fields you had me make. Still seems odd to have to "preserve" them that way when machineModels should have been left alone to start with.

Comment: @RMW If you do not post `machineModels` ,it will not have values in handler.My code is added to the form along with your original <select>.See mu updated code

Comment: So everything in the Model that I bind to the View will be cleared by the View prior to reaching the OnPost handler if I don't post all of the bound Model properties? Even if a property wasn't bound with a "BindProperty" but was instead only referenced via the "items=xxx" in a "select" statement?

Comment: @RMW I think you have misunderstood the concept.It is not being cleared but not sending the data in your post request.You could always press F12 to check the request in network tab

Comment: When I say it has been cleared, I mean that, on the first line of the handler, I use the debugger to examine the value of the property that is way up at the start of my cshtml.cs file. I hover over the definition of the property there and it says it is empty. I'm not looking at any variable in the handler. I'm unfamiliar with F12. Is that a command for the browser or Visual Studio?

Comment: @RMW Ok, I know.Since you do not send so you do not achieve it. F12 means the `F12` key onyour keyboard , if you press it in browser, it will show developer tools, in network tab, you could see all request.Anyway,do you get the data using above code with  above code?

Comment: Thanks for info on F12. I can see what is sent to the handler when the POST occurs. Using your code, I can see that the machineModels we put the hidden inputs on ARE SENT. But as I said in a previous comment, why is the machineModels property in my Model being cleared? With your code I can get the machineModels info to the handler, but why did the POST clear the property in the first place? Why did I have to resort to putting the hidden inputs in? Was expecting the POST to leave machineModels alone and just change machineModel in the Model. If it also posted machineModel, I was ok with that.

Comment: @RMW As I said, you just pass `machineModels` from get handler to view but it will not posting back to handler automatically, F12 request data could also check that.The hidden inputs are used to post back manually (from page to handler) and use hidden type since maybe you do not want to show it.Finally, yes, you do not need to pay attention to `machineModels`  at all, it just provides the list of select options, if you want to get in post handler, then still use the way you have done before

Comment: Thanks Xing but I think you and I are not in sync on what I'm asking. I build up machineModels with code in my Model, and the View uses it to display some select options, but I don't want machineModels returned to me - but I do want the View to leave machineModels alone so I can use it for other reasons than in a POST handler sometime after the handler finishes. I can't use machineModels for anything after the handler runs because it has been cleared out. If the View would just display it and leave it alone I would be fine. Want to figure out what in my setup of the Model/View is clearing it.

Comment: The answer to why machineModels is cleared is because HTML was designed to be that way, was designed to be stateless, designed that values should normally not be remembered from one request to the next. Just because the code to fill a variable was outside of a OnPost or a OnGet does not mean that it is safe from being cleared. All of the initialization-like code in the cs file associated with a Razor  page is re-run every time a request is sent to the cs file. The variables are cleared because of that re-run of that code. Put a breakpt there and see that it's executed at every request.